# How to upload local image by drag and drop on selenium

Tags: java, image, selenium, upload

I'm trying to upload local image on Selenium.
The website can accept file only drag and drop.

Selenium IDE works well.

[image]

but I can't upload image by `elesemnt.sendKey();`

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='image1']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='image1']")).sendKeys("/Users/trmt_8/Desktop/BUYMA/1.png");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='image2']")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='image2']")).sendKeys("/Users/trmt_8/Desktop/BUYMA/38565487.png");
```

How can I upload image?

Comment: The web site accept only drag and drop.It doen't have upload button.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? Nothing happens? `NoSuchElementException`?

Answer (score 0):

When I used Google chrome and chorome_driver, I could upload image.(*^^*)

You can download form here --->
[ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)